# Meteor: Possible to check if application has already open instance on another computer?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is it possible to check for an unique client in meteor? This sounds a little strange. Let me explain it:

I want to let my meteor app only work at one computer at the same time. But I can't use the IP for checking, as there are also computers in a same network, so there would be the same IP for the external sever.

If somebody open the app on a second computer, all other (opened) app instances on other computer should be logged out (or something like this).

Is this technical possible in meteor?

**Update**

Please note that I don't want to block a second login, but I want to logout on all other devices if the user do a login.

Comment: Set a flag in the database and route to a view: "View currently unavailable please come back later?"

Comment: Could you please give me a quick example as I don't completely understand what you mean by setting a flag :-( And yes, routing (using IronRouter) to a view would be exactly what I want to do. But I still stack on the "check"...

Comment: Write a simple function on if(Meteor.isClient) . Instantiate a server side collection and fill it with Client is on website equals true. As long as this flag is set don't route anywhere else other than: view not available, please come back later. In case it is false, route to the point where you want your user to be.

Comment: are you requiring the user to have an account?

Comment: Yes. The Users have Accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

meteor has in built function for this

please Check

`Meteor.logoutOtherClients([callback])`

[Meteor Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_logoutotherclients)

Comment: This doesn't log out all other users, just other devices logged in as the same user

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I may have misunderstood the question, this is for making sure the user is only logged in at one device at a time.  Not only one user at a time.

Not only is it possible, it's built in. Check out the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_logoutotherclients)

Call `Meteor.logoutOtherClients()` on login to logout other clients logged in as the same user.

**/client/lib/hooks.js**

```
Accounts.onLogin(function () {
    Meteor.logoutOtherClients(function (error) {
        if (error) {
            //Error handling goes here
            console.log(error)
        }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Server callback [validateLoginAttempt](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validateloginattempt), and delete all the loginTokens from [Meteor.users](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users) before logging in a user.

Example requires `accounts-ui` and `accounts-password` packages.

`./single.html:`

```
<head>
  <title>SingleUserSystem</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
  {{> loginButtons}}
  {{> main}}
</body>

<template name="main">
  <div id="name">
    {{#if currentUser}}
      <h1>Logged In!</h1>
      <h3>Another user logging in will log you out.</h3>
    {{else}}
      <h1>Logged Out!</h1>
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

`./single.js:`

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // Server Callback on all login attempts
  Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(attempt) {
    if (!attempt.allowed)  // If login attempt was going to fail we
      return false;        // should not log out currently logged in user

    // deleting loginTokens from Meteor.users collection logs out users
    Meteor.users.update(
              {},
              {$set: { 'services.resume.loginTokens': [] } },
              {multi: true}
            );

    return true;   // return true to allow login to succeed
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mac address. Even if they are in the same network they have different mac addresses
 + since you have users and account, you can have just have a place somewhere online, set the user when someone logs in and only allow other user to use the app if no one is logged in.
So to make it more clear, have a blank input somewhere online. Every time someone logs in, set the input's text with the user's credentials or something else depending on you.
When an other user tries to use it, have it check if the input is blank. If not means it is occupied.

Still I believe Mac address solution is the easiest and the best.

Edit: This is how every connections looks like on your router

```
Wed, 14 Oct 2015 20:10:51 GMT IP=192.168.1.3 MAC=someaddershere
Wed, 14 Oct 2015 19:13:58 GMT IP=192.168.1.4 MAC=someaddershere
Wed, 14 Oct 2015 18:40:51 GMT IP=192.168.1.3 MAC=someaddershere
Wed, 14 Oct 2015 18:40:47 GMT IP=192.168.1.3 MAC=someaddershere
Wed, 14 Oct 2015 17:43:57 GMT IP=192.168.1.4 MAC=someaddershere
Wed, 14 Oct 2015 17:10:43 GMT IP=192.168.1.3 MAC=someaddershere
```

There are so many solutions here, dates, mac addresses, times, ips

Comment: Hmm. That sounds interesting, but my problem is how to logout all the other devices. Taking your example for the login at 20:10:51 all other devices where the user is already logged in should be logged out...

Comment: I am having difficulties following you... When you performs a login to the app, have it check if someone is already logged in and prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to accomplish this.

For example, lets use the [Mizzao user status package](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status)

And then lets say you have something like

```
"click .login":function(event, template){
 var queryUsersOnline = Meteor.users.find({ "status.online": true });
 if(query){
  //this means someone is online
  alert("Sorry you can access now"); //or
  Router.go("notAccessRoute");
  }
}
```

Now another possible solution.

Lets say you have this collection only serverside.

```
//Server side only
UserOnlineFlag = new Mongo.Collection('userOnlineFlag');
```

now use the [Meteor.loggingIn()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loggingin) function

```
callback = function(){
 if(Meteor.user()){
  Meteor.call('insertUserOnlineFlag');
 }
}

Meteor.loggingIn(callback);
```

Then on the server

```
Meteor.methods({
 insertUserOnlineFlag:function(){
  UserOnlineFlag.insert({someOneOnline:true});
 },
 checkUserStatus:function(){
    var query = UserOnlineFlag.findOne();
    if(query){
    throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Already someone online");
    }else{
     return {message:"welcome to the stackoverflow question app"};
    }
  }
});
```

Now on your login event something like this.

```
"click .login":function(event, template){
     Meteor.call("checkUserStatus",function(){
       if(error){
            console.log(error.message);
        }else{
           console.log(result.message);
        }
     })
    }
```

**NOTE** this is conceptual code, just to give you and idea, and i hope you get the idea

Good luck =D

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but I need it just the other way round: I don't want to block a second login, but I want to do a logout on the other screens, if the user is logging in on another pc.